# Adding SSD boot disk to machine running RAID 10

Tags: windows-7, raid, ssd, bios, megaraid

I have a server (dev rig) that runs Windows 2008 R2 and boots from a RAID 10 setup.

Now I want to add an SSD disk that will contain Windows 7 (could be dual boot, but dont plan on salvaging the existing OS setup as it only contains virtual machines that i can re-attach from the RAID disk after i reinstall Windows 2008 R2 on the SSD too.

How do i configure this in BIOS so that I have both SSD and RAID 10 and so that it no longer boots from RAID but from SSD instead? The BIOS is set up as RAID, not AHCI/IDE

Hardware: 
ASUS Z8NA-D6 motherboard
AMIBIOS v 0501 (9/15/09)
ICH10R LSI RAID (embedded MegaRaid)

[Mobo manual](http://support.asus.com/download/download_item_mkt.aspx?os=17&f_type=34&slanguage=en-us&model=Z8NA-D6)